# RVM unable to set ruby as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

Every morning I need to fire this command

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

otherwise it was unable recognise the `rails s` or any command.

I have installed rvm for `multiuser on ubuntu 12.04`

**Update:**

rvm list ->

```
rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ i686 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Please suggest..

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: can you paste the output of rvm list ? If you are using different ruby version for different rails project then please refer this blog post : http://news-anand.blogspot.in/2013/05/use-different-ruby-version-for.html

Comment: what version of rvm is that? have you ran and read `rvm get head`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the deault ruby version using the command :

```
rvm use --default ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

After this command, everytime you open a new terminal, ruby-1.9.3-p448 will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Have you set your terminal as a login terminal? Without doing so, you won't be able to set any default rubies and RVM will not work completely.

https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal